# Is there any way to feed output of a shell script to google sheet?

Tags: google, uptime

I wanted to to make some reports on uptime of some a using google sheet. I wanted to update google sheet every day with the reports. I wanted to make  report of  uptime of at least   100 computers running on linux.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, but there is a steep learning curve. You will need to do a lot of reading and experimenting first.

Access to Google Documents is possible through the use of the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/). Basically, the steps are:

1. Create a Gmail address if you don't already have one.
2. Create a project and set its permissions. Google gives you an API key.
3. Download and install Google libraries.
4. Write a program in a suitable language (there are a few to choose from). Authentication is the hardest step. This is where you need the API key.
5. You can now create Google documents.

The documentation isn't perfect and you will need a lot of visits to Stackexchange sites to make it work. As such, this question is out of the scope of this site.

EDIT: what you want to achieve could possible be done much easier by writing your data as a CSV (character separated values) file, uploading that to Internet and sharing the link. Everyone with the link could then open the file with e.g. LibreOffice or Excel.